# React Native Expo ScreenOrientation.getOrientationAsync() function returns 1

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to use the ScreenOrientation library to find the device's orientation in expo.

```
ScreenOrientation.getOrientationAsync().then((data) => console.log(data));
```

However, instead of an Orientation object, the function console logs the number 1. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The number represents a screen orientation. 1 means PORTRAIT_UP

source: https://forums.expo.io/t/react-native-expo-screenorientation-getorientationasync-function-returns-1/40846

Link to the code that shows the list of numbers: https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/sdk-38/packages/expo-screen-orientation/src/ScreenOrientation.types.ts